# Number of flight legs criterion for Star Alliance Gold instead of miles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, air-india, star-alliance

Typically, Star Alliance Gold status is granted on the basis of a number of status miles flown in a year.

I am wondering, are there airlines which also grant status based on a certain minimum number of flight legs flown, regardless of miles?

Specifically, I am wondering for Air India, but I cannot seem to find that information on their website. So I presume they grant status only on the basis of status miles?

Answer (score 2):

[Asiana Airline](https://flyasiana.com/C/KR/EN/contents/elite-membership-upgrade-requirement) does it. For example, to upgrade to Gold:

> If any of the following conditions have been met during the 24-month period from the “base date*”
>
> 1. 20,000 flight miles accrued
> 2. 30 flights with Asiana Airlines
> 3. 20,000 total miles accrued (when flight mileage is over 15,000 and combined with Asiana affiliate card records)

Comment: Those numbers will get you "Asiana Gold", which is Star Alliance SILVER, not Gold.

Comment: Principle stays the same for upper tiers. Just more flights (50) *or* miles for Diamond. Etc...

Comment: @dda, can you please edit those higher tiers into the answer, even if you have to do so without details.